# How to make ‘image as planes” cast shadow but not be visible?

Tags: rendering, node-editor, shaders, image

How to make ‘image as planes” cast shadow but not be visible? I only want to see the women’s shadow under her feet but not actually see her. Thanks.

[image]

Current node set up in Cycles:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to uncheck *Ray Visibility* -> *Camera* for the plane and keep the shadows.

[image]

Comment: That’s the ticket. Thank you!